# Invalid Apache directory using an wmware window's shared folder as directory root

Tags: apache, directory, shared-directory, vmware-player

I have made an virtual environment with VMware and a Cent-OS 5 distribution, i also made a shared folder from windows into my VMware virtual machine to share my project and run it locally under a Linux environment. The problem is that when i try to change my document root in Apache and restart it. it says that my shared folder that is located in Linux is not a valid directory (Invalid Apache directory ). From what i have read it might be something to do with rights but as far as now i have not been able to change any rights for that shared folder at Cent-OS 5.